# Construct query(s) for table copy/update MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Currently looking to extract data from 2 tables and insert into another.
Tables as follows (with example ideal data):

```
Table1
T1ID(PK)  T1Field1
301       2011-07-01
302       2011-07-01

Table2
T2ID(PK)  T2Field2  T2Field3  T2Field4
521       301       555       Apple
522       301       666       Pear


Table3 (new table)
T3Field1  T3Field2     T3Field3    T3Field4
301       2011-07-01   555         Apple
301       2011-07-01   666         Pear
```

Looking for the fewest and most efficient query's to use in order to do the following:

1. `Insert T1ID into T3Field1  + Insert T1Field1 into T3Field2`
2. `Update T3Field3 where T3Field1 = T2Field2 (for each) -`*

Have simply used mysql insert for the first query. This NEEDS to be done first as it contains timestamp information.

*Attempted INNER JOIN here with no luck since there is a one-to-many and only the first row would get inserted.

I could select all of the results and then while loop / update within for each record but am trying to keep this as minimal as possible.

Just need a second opinion on the logic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the below code and it matches your ideal data. But, second row of `Table1` is lost since there is no corresponding match for it in `Table2`

```
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT 
Table1.T1ID AS T3Field1,
Table1.T1Field1 AS T3Field2,
Table2.T2Field3 AS T3Field3,
Table2.T2Field4 AS T3Field4
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE
Table1.T1ID = Table2.T2field2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and example code. I have attempted to build the query in this way, and I have managed to get data from both tables into the new table. The actual database is much bigger and I need to get data from many more tables within the same query so currently getting row value errors due to missing data. 

I will post back again should I have any further issues. Thanks again.

Comment: It will surely get more and more complex with additional tables. The right order and outer joins will possibly solve your problem.